# How do you make the first person object the main camera?

Tags: unity, unityscript

How can a first person object character be made to be the primary viewing camera in unityscript? Do I remove the main camera? or just turn one or the other on/off?

Comment: I believe the Unity first person controller prefab sets its own camera to the default. So you should be able to delete the default "Main Camera" object that is created when you open a new scene.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the whichever camera you intend to use as the "first-person" camera should be a child of the character game object. Remove any other cameras.

Comment: Instead of removing all other cameras, I'd learn about camera depths, and then remove unnecessary cameras: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera-depth.html

Answer (score 1):

Unity will use the first camera tagged as `MainCamera`, so you'll need to change the tag of the camera you want to be main and remove the tag from the old main (or just delete it).

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 1 camera in the scene you will have to change their `Depths` accordingly.

Also, unless you have a specific reason for having more than 1 camera (for example, render textures, GUI camera, split screen, etc) you should just delete any unnecessary cameras.

And to access `Camera.main` you should simply tag your camera as `Main Camera`.